# Saving textBlock on image

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

I have found many examples for Windows Phone 8/8.1, but I can't seem to find one for Window 10 UWP.

So what I need is a moveable textBlock on an image. I just don't seem to know how to load the image, write some text and then save it.

Code I currently have [that does not work]

```
//first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
            Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
            SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

            //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
            img.Dispose();
            drawing.Dispose();

            //create a new image of the right size
            img = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

            drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            //paint the background
            drawing.Clear(backColor);

            //create a brush for the text
            Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

            drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

            drawing.Save();

            textBrush.Dispose();
            drawing.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need RenderTargetBitmap here is an example for Windows Store apps( 8.1) and is still valid for UWP apps
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx

Here is the MSDN documentation for UWP apps with RenderTargetBitmap 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298548

I recommend you to put your textblock inside of a Grid (container) and follow the examples.

Best Regards

Comment: Please mark this answer if it is useful for you! Thank you!